# .htaccess rule matching too much

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to use .htaccess to recognize a url with no trailing file path.

This is my entire .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# AnyTown Portal
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)?anytownnews\..+\..{3}(?!\/(.+)) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ anytownnews.php [QSA,NC,L,DPI]
```

Four different regex parsers on the web report that this regex correctly recognizes:

```
anytownnews.test.com
```

as a match and

```
anytownnews.test.com/junk
```

as a non match.

However, apache matches this rule to both of the URLs and performs the replacement.

What have I missed here?

I also tried just this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?anytownnews\..+\..{3}(?!\/(.+)) anytownnews.php [QSA,NC,L,DPI,END]
```

Which passes both my test cases when tested here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

But this expression is completely ignored by apache.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the URL you're trying to match and what you don't want to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems like you want this to happen

```
anytownnews.test.com -> rewritten to /anytownnews.php
anytownnews.test.com/folder/ -> don't rewrite
anytownnews.test.com/page1.html -> don't rewrite
```

This appears to achieve just that

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^anytownnews\..+\..{3} [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /anytownnews.php [QSA,NC,L,DPI]
```

Further, you can do this and capture the subdomain and use it in the RewriteRule, if that is your intent

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.|signup\.)([a-z0-9-]+)\..+\..{3} [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1.php [QSA,NC,L,DPI]
```

Note `%1.php` is used, rather than `$1` because I'm using a backreference from a Rewrite Condition.

The regex will exclude from rewriting certain subdomains (currently set to www and signup, as examples). If you don't want to exclude any subdomains, just use.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+)\..+\..{3} [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1.php [QSA,NC,L,DPI]
```